# rails 4 Devise 4 Invitable - Params Sanitizer not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

I am using Devise Invitable in my rails 4 app, I have some extra fields that the user needs to fill out when they set their password.

I have created the invitation controller and added the extra fields to the update_sanitized_params method in the controller. When I fill out the form the server out put gives me:

```
Started PUT "/users/invitation" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-11 12:57:34 -0600
Processing by InvitationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"c0c75noldd9hB6pHjLh1A74KWsWGrIc/K4s7PUJkmtnCG9Uz3YMEJMiBKSpC8Fk+ObC67oBx6E5AxS0R/xZlUA==", "user"=>{"f_name"=>"Steve", "l_name"=>"Jenkinson", "date_of_birth"=>"1975-01-01", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Accept Invitation"}
  Account Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."subdomain" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["subdomain", "10-106security"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering devise/invitations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/invitations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (2.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_signed_out_nav.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 53.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

However the user attributes are not being saved. This was verified in rails console.

Console Output after submitting the Invitation Edit form:

```
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<User id: 3, email: "test1@test.com", f_name: nil, l_name: nil, date_of_birth: nil, employee_number: nil, system_id: nil, created_at: "2016-10-11 19:33:33", updated_at: "2016-10-11 19:33:33", invitation_token: "d7024926f142aeeec1d23781f1832f74317b592f5bcdd5e6a3...", invitation_created_at: "2016-10-11 19:33:33", invitation_sent_at: "2016-10-11 19:33:33", invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_type: "User", invited_by_id: 1, invitations_count: 0>
```

my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  # Before Actions
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :load_schema, :authenticate_user!, :set_mailer_host

  # Custom Methods

  private

  def load_schema
    Apartment::Tenant.switch!('public')
    return unless request.subdomain.present?

    if current_account
      Apartment::Tenant.switch!(current_account.subdomain)
    else
      redirect_to root_url(subdomain: false)
    end
  end

  def current_account
    @current_account ||= Account.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
  end
  helper_method :current_account

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    new_user_session_path
  end

  def set_mailer_host
    subdomain = current_account ? "#{current_account.subdomain}." : ""
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "#{subdomain}lvh.me:3000"
  end

  def after_invite_path_for(resource)
    users_path
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:f_name, :l_name, :date_of_birth, :password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token])
  end

end
```

and here is the form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => invitation_path(resource_name), method: :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :f_name, label: 'First Name' %>
  <%= f.text_field :l_name, label: 'Last Name' %>
  <%= f.date_field :date_of_birth, label: 'Date Of Birth' %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, label: 'Password' %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, label: 'Confirm Password' %>
  <%= f.submit "Accept Invitation", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

here is the User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Before Actions

  # Devise Modules
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  # Relationships

  # Validations
  validates :f_name, presence: true
  validates :l_name, presence: true
  validates :date_of_birth, presence: true

  # Custom Methods
  def full_name
    l_name.upcase + ", " + f_name
  end

end
```

any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem here was that upon editing the devise_invitable form the user would fill out, I did not add the authentication token.